# http request header showing ??? for non-english cyrillic characters while sending email

Tags: http, amazon-ec2, http-headers, jetty

I am using cyrillic characters in mail content and subject, by setting Content-Type as "text/html; charset=UTF-8" I am able to pass to the MimeMessage and could read the same characters in the mail content and subject line.

But, when I have sender or recipient names with such characters, names for the mail ids are displayed as ????.

My environment is : normal servlet class, application running on Jetty server in EC2 machine, with JDK 1.7.
I have tested for JDK 1.7 and Jetty, no issues with them.

Do I need make any changes in the HttpRequest header?

I also tried with Java API and Postman App as well. The result is same.

Comment: What header fields do these appear in?

Comment: Are you calling ServletResponse.setCharacterEncoding?